# How to transfer C# Windows form (.NET Framework) from one PC to another PC

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, .net-framework-version

As you could guess, I'm an absolute beginner to Visual Studios and C# Windows Forms (.NET Framework). I want to transfer my project from my laptop to my PC but I have no idea how to do so. I've been trying for quite a while but can't seem to get what files to copy. I'm copying the [Name].cs , [Name].Designer.cs and [Name].resx files but I can't seem to get them to work. should I copy the whole folder or .sln file or what?

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Yes, if you want to open the project in Visual studio on another computer you need to copy the solution file as well - you probably want to copy everythig except the build files (which should be its own sub-directory if set up correctly)

Comment: There should be a top-level folder containing a .sln file. Copy that and all folders under it.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the whole root directory where the .sln is or .csproj if it is a single winforms project.
On the destination computer you might need some prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to work on it and update it from both places, use GitHub and make a private repository. That's an easy way. The other way is follow the file path: C:\users\admin\source\repos and find your project in that list of folders. You could copy it to a flash drive, if you wanted to do it that way.